# I can't get Opera to work on selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get Opera to work but there is always an error

I followed this thread, and have exactly the same issues  [Unable to launch Opera using Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59815011/unable-to-launch-opera-using-python-selenium)
They didn't solve the problem

Then same OP did this [URL opening fails with Opera using python selenium library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59827391/url-opening-fails-with-opera-using-python-selenium-library) and was closed because of reposting the same issue (was not the same issue, now it has another error)

this time is this one:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.opera.options import Options

options = Options() 
options.binary_location = OperaPath #path to .exe 
driver = webdriver.Opera(options=options, executable_path= OperaPath)
```

***Opera.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0***

> operadriver=86.0.4240.80
>
> Opera 72
>
> Windows 10, 64 bits
>
> Python 3.8.1

Comment: What are the versions of your webdriver and web browser?

Comment: I wrote it on the original post:

operadriver=86.0.4240.80

Opera 72

Windows 10, 64 bits

Python 3.8.1;

edit:oh you mean the Selenium webdriver... wait, brb

Comment: Selenium is 3.141.0

Was that what you asked?